# How to access IConfigurationRoot in all classes

Tags: maui

I created this method in the MauiApp `AddAppSetting` and its reading in my json file. The problem I am having is how can i access the data in all of my classes with out passing in any parameter?

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{

    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .UseTelerik()
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
        });

    builder.AddAppSetting();

    return builder.Build();
}

public static void AddAppSetting(this MauiAppBuilder builder)
{
   using Stream stream = Assembly
       .GetExecutingAssembly()
       .GetManifestResourceStream("AppMaui.appsettings.json");
       if (stream != null)
          {
                IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .AddJsonStream(stream)
                        .Build();
                builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(config);
          }
}
```

Class where I like to access the config file.

```
 public abstract class MobileAPIServiceBase
 {
     private readonly string _rootUrl;
     private readonly string _commonQueryString;

     IConfiguration configuration;
     protected MobileAPIServiceBase()
     {
         
     }

}
```

I am using the DerivateClass but its asking me to return a type.
[image]

Comment: your constructor is wrong, it should be `DerivateClass(IConfiguration configuration)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection)

first, you need to use a derivative class, you cannot create an instance of an abstract class

```cs
public abstract class MobileAPIServiceBase
 {
     private readonly string _rootUrl;
     private readonly string _commonQueryString;

     IConfiguration configuration;
     protected MobileAPIServiceBase(IConfiguration configuration)
     {
         this.configuration = configuration; 
     }
}

public class DerivateClass : MobileAPIServiceBase
{
     public DerivateClass(IConfiguration configuration) :base(configuration)
     {
         
     }
}
```

after that, add it to your container of dependency injection

```cs
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{

    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .UseTelerik()
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
        });

    builder.AddAppSetting();
builder.Services.AddTransient<DerivateClass>();

    return builder.Build();
}
```

Then, you can inject the derived class anywhere

```
public class MyPage: ContentPage
{
private readonly DerivateClass _derivateClass
     protected MyPage(DerivateClass derivateClass) 
     {
         _derivateClass = derivateClass;
     }
}
```

Comment: in the DerivateClass  what do I return?

Comment: i fixed the code, please take a look now

Comment: any idea why configuration is null in the abstract?